# Getting Google IdToken for service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-signin

I have a backend that is serving android clients, authenticating them with IdToken sent from the android app.
Now, I need to authenticate a service running on aws that is using my apis. So I figured a service account would do the trick, using the private pem file to create a IdToken and send it along just as the android clients do. But I find no way of obtaining an IdToken with these credentials. Is this possible (preferrably in nodejs).
Or am I on the wrong path here?

Comment: Question - Which APIs are these - your own APIs or these are google cloud APIs ? Service accounts only are meant as a way for delegation with respect to Google Cloud APIs. For example, if you want your service or third party to call only a subset of APIs, service accounts can be used for that. For your use case, I think you should be looking into Cloud Endpoints and API keys.

Comment: Yes, this is to authenticate for my own apis. However from an outside server that is also "mine". My idea was to give the serviceaccount no rights at all, just to be used to assert identity. CloudEndpoints would (?) impose another implementation, I am using spring. But is there a way to get an IdToken from a serviceaccount and its private file?

Answer (score 5):

I know this is older, but I found this question and it didn't lead me to the answer I ended up with.

I followed the guide in https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication#using_a_google_id_token with some mix of https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto, which mentioned that the key to this was to include a `target_audience` claim in the generated JWT.

So, essentially I made a JWT that looked like:

```
{
  "exp": 1547576771,
  "iat": 1547575906,
  "aud":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
  "target_audience": "https://example.com/",
  "iss": EMAIL OF SERVICE ACCOUNT
}
```

and posted that to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` with params `grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer` and `assertion=<THE JWT>`

Without `target_audience` the endpoint gave me an access token, but with it I got an `id_token` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Grettings since 2020

I had problems in Java for take ID_TOKEN of a Google Service Account. My project had two years  and i were using GoogleCredentials, fromStream method and a JSON credential, but this class didn't gave me ID_TOKEN, only access_token on a not JWT format.

I solved because on this years Google updated here java code for authentication, for take ID_TOKEN you must use this library https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-auth-library-credentials</artifactId>
    <version>0.20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And then use ServiceAccountCredential

```
String credPath = "/path/to/svc_account.json";
ServiceAccountCredentials sourceCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials
     .fromStream(new FileInputStream(credPath));
```

When you create this class, itself will authenticate with google and have a access_token,refreshToken...

For extract ID_TOKEN you must use this function:

```
String audience = "http://localhost"; //Your server domain
IdToken idToken = credential.idTokenWithAudience(audience, new ArrayList<IdTokenProvider.Option>());
String id_token =  idToken.getTokenValue();
```

And with this you have a JWT token.

I hope this help people like me,that are trying get ID_TOKEN.

Comment: I used to generate a JWT access token from service-account json file with header contains the API client-id, using which I generate the id-token.  In the above code, where can  I specify the client-id of the API?

Comment: The client-id usually where declarated on account service on format JSON

Comment: in case you use the env var , spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS} , how would you get the "GoogleCredentials" ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use service accounts generated for Google Cloud APIs to directly authenticate against your own APIs. How will you know which service account private keys are valid and which have been revoked? Google does not expose this information.

Service accounts are rather meant for delegation of credentials. When you access Google Cloud platform service, you will be authenticating with your google account credentials. You will not want to provision the very same credentials everywhere your running code needs to access any of the Google cloud services (i.e. Cloud APIs). Instead you create service accounts whose scope can be reduced to a subset of the scope of your google account credentials. This way a particular piece of code can be limited to only a few set of APIs.

> [**Service Accounts**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts)
>
> A service account is a special account that can be used by services
>   and applications running on your Google Compute Engine instance to
>   interact with other Google Cloud Platform APIs. Applications can use
>   service account credentials to authorize themselves to a set of APIs
>   and perform actions within the permissions granted to the service
>   account and virtual machine instance.
>
> **What are service accounts?**
>
> Service accounts authenticate applications running on your virtual
>   machine instances to other Google Cloud Platform services. For
>   example, if you write an application that reads and writes files on
>   Google Cloud Storage, it must first authenticate to the Google Cloud
>   Storage API. You can create a service account and grant the service
>   account access to the Cloud Storage API. Then, you would update your
>   application code to pass the service account credentials to the Cloud
>   Storage API. In this way, your application authenticates seamlessly to
>   the API without embedding any secret keys or user credentials in your
>   instance, image, or application code.

I know where your confusion stems, it is because service account also have the same OAuth model you are used to.

You can use service accounts to get access tokens and refresh them as needed, but the scope of authentication is at the very maximum limited to the surface of the Google Cloud APIs. You will not be able to mix and match your APIs with that.

Alternative is to either build your own authentication model (which is not so clear from your question when you say `authenticating them with IdToken sent from the android app`) or rely on something like [Cloud endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/about-cloud-endpoints) which you create and manage APIs along with API keys for authentication.

As you already mentioned in one of your comments, you can follow the [Service-to-Service authentication](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/service-to-service-auth) guide which describes how you can use Google Cloud Service accounts to authenticate with your APIs running on Google Cloud Endpoint.

It supports using `Google ID JWT` tokens. The caller will have to send the JWT to Google Token endpoints to obtain a `Google ID` token and then use this `Google ID` token in all of your requests. This approach also has the advantage that you only have to whitelist the `Google ID` token server in your API configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Tuxdude, for a rich and informative answer :o)!  

The idea is to use google IdTokens for authenticating requests, which is the recomended way for android apps where you get an IdToken from SSO/GooglePlayServices and some setup in cloudconsole-credentials. Hence, I would prefer other users (i.e. servers) to use the same mechanism.

Comment: I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/service-to-service-auth#using_a_google_id_token), that do suggest that this can be done the way I hoped, by letting servers create a jwt signed with private key, then sent to google to get an IdToken back. I tried and its works fine (as for functionality) but from your answer above I am now worried that I misunderstand the case and that this may not be safe... :o/

Comment: As long as you're using the token with one of the Google Cloud APIs, it will work. Cloud Endpoints is a google cloud service and can hence authenticate the caller. So you're on the right track with using Service accounts and Cloud Endpoints. Sorry, I should have made this clear in the answer, will update now.

Comment: The main thing that the docs and this answer are not clear about is the " send the JWT to Google Token endpoints to obtain a Google ID token" part.  One can use ```service_account.Crendentials.from_service_accizbt_file('path/to/file.json')```, but that crendential object has no token (and thereby no 'id_token' field).